# What is wrong with my kalanchoe plant?

Tags: kalanchoe

I got this kalanchoe plant in October 2021 when I moved to Cardiff, UK. It was flowing back then. It had lots of flowers. But after the flowering season, i removed the dried wilted flowers, and since then it has not flowered. I have not even seen a single bud since then. I re-potted the plant as it outgrew its original small pot. I used a potting mix which i got from amazon. I don't water it daily, i water it once the soil dries up (i check by inserting my pinky finger one inch deep, if it's dry only then i water) I don't know what I'm doing wrong, because i can see only leaves and no buds. Also there are a few roots growing over the stems, is that normal? What should I do inorder for my plant to flower? Also the stems did not grow from the place i cut them after the flowers wilted. Also the leaf size has become small, earlier when i had got them, the leaves were much bigger, but now though they are growing tall, the leaf size is pretty small.[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]